# Where to start learning Solidity

Tags: solidity

Short and sweet. I'm new to coding and this website. I hope someone can tell me where I can start learning solidity. I'm watching a 16 hour YouTube video currently to learn, but how did people get so good at solidity in the first place?

I want to become good at making smart contracts and working with blockchain so I can benefit from the crypto boom.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

There are several sources:

- OpenZeppelin contract's README has a section for learning about the ecosystem, Check [Learn More](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts#learn-more).
- The ethereum founfation also give [many resources](https://ethereum.org/en/developers/learning-tools/), including bootcamps, documentation and interactive games.

I would suggest the [Chainshot](https://www.chainshot.com/) bootcamp listed on the ethereum foundation page.